# Set UIView Background Color to UITableViewSelectionStyle Default

Tags: swift

I have created a UIView that is not in a UITableView or UITableViewCell. I'd like to be able to highlight this view within the view's touchesBegan function and the backgroundColor of this UIView the same color as this cell. Below is the code that I'm using. Unfortunately, it seems like .lightgray is not the same color used for selectionStyle = .default. Is there another way that I can set this view to the same color used by the UITableViewCells?

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.backgroundView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
}
```

Comment: I'm a little bit confused. Do you want the backgroundView to have the same color as the selected color of tableView cell?

Comment: @LinhTa Yes, that is exactly what I want. I want to be able to make this view that exists outside of the tableview to emulate the behavior of the tableviewcells when selected, for visual consistency.

Comment: You can select a cell, take a screenshot of it and use Digical Color Meter to get the hex color